# Django: Update multiple objects attributes

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Is there a more efficient way of do this maybe with F expressions? Some how to reducing hitting the DB?

```
# 1st way hits DB twice per object
def something():
  pks = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0]
  for i in range(len(pks)):
    mymodel.objects.get(pk=pks[i]).update(attr=i)

# 2nd way hits DB once per obj and once for the queryset
def something():
  pks = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0]
  order = Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(pks)])
  query = mymodel.objects.filter(pk__in=pks).order_by(order)
  for i in range(len(query)):
    query[i].attr = i
    query[i].save()
```

Editing to move variables consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally making multiple database queries instead of one large query is to be avoided. However your case seems to be an exception. (Note: I am making this answer based on the information provided. Please don't edit your question to say I actually meant ....)

The following query will be very fast no matter how many records you have because it's retrieving a single item from a primary key. All RDBMS are designed to handle this really well.

```
mymodel.objects.get(pk=a[i])
```

Hower you can make your function more efficient like this:

```
def something():
  pks = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0]
  for i in range(len(a)):
    mymodel.objects.filter(pk=a[i]).update(attr=i)
```

Now it hits the DB only once per object. the above query just translates to

```
 UPDATE mapp_mymodel SET attr=i where pk=1
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between get and filter? You say that get is very fast because it's retrieving an item but use filter in your code. I generally used filter if I wanted more than one object and get for one object.

Comment: The difference between get and filter is that get fetches an object and then makes the update as you have discovered. Filter does not actually retrieve anything from the database until you take a slice from it or iterate through it.

Comment: I thought this would hit the DB 2 times because once to get the object then once more to update said object.

Comment: Okay I get it now! Thanks for the help! Had to make multiple comments for some reason.

Comment: Please also see the update. filter is not faster (or slower) than get. What's fast is using a primary key to query a database. Generally you don't need to worry too much about repeating such a query 4 or 5 times

Comment: glad to be of help. all the best with your project

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you can do something like

```
pks = [4, 2, 1, 3, 0]
mymodel.object.filter(pk__in=pks).update(attr='test')
```

Unless you are trying to use the for loop index as the attribute value, in which this does not work.

Comment: Acccording to the OP's qestion. when pk=i, attr=i (each attr is different) that's why I added that caveat to my answer. In the above query. attr=1 for all instances

Comment: Thought this might be the case (hence the last line of the answer). But posted it just incase. Your answer seems more helpful. Thanks..

Comment: Yes I'm using the index as the value for attr.